# How to get the entry index in a query with ORDER BY

Tags: jpa, jpql

I need to figure out a way to get the index of every entry in a query result, let me show an example:

Suppose we have 3 entries in the `Person` table.

- Willie
- Mike
- Alan

And I want to query that table to return all it's entries, and I want to know the index in which they are returned, with [`JPQL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language)

A Pseudo code would be like this:

```
SELECT [INDEX], p.name FROM Person p ORDER BY p.name
```

What should I replace `[INDEX]` with to get a result like this:

```
1 - Alan
2 - Mike
3 - Willie
```

Is there a way to do that using JPQL?

Comment: Do you know that JPQL returns you a `List`, and that a `List` is inherently ordered?

Comment: Yes yes, I am aware of that, it's just that in this particular case, I need that ordering inside the query result. If there is no other way, I will use the List index, but I wanted to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a database function and call it using FUNC() (EclipseLink) or FUNCTION() (JPA 2.1) from JPQL.  EclipseLink also supports SQL() to embed any SQL you want inside JPQL.  Or you could use a native query, or just add the index in Java code, since you really don't need to select it from the database.